# Redirect consecutive tail output to UI

Tags: java, grails, groovy, tail

Iam new to grails .In view i have to display the consecutive tail logs from a server file.
for that iam using Jsch library to ssh to a server and executing tail command  tail -n 1 -f access.log
At the same time i need to redirect the consecutive tail logs to UI.

So in controllert class i have created a method to read the tail output as below.But my intention is to
display the live streaming in UI as well.

Here if user press the stop button isLogStreaming will be false and quit the tail operation.The streaming 
will have display in the UI until user press stop button.

How i can implement this in using groovy on grails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide log streaming to UI using **Server Send Events**.

Here is clear official example how to implement it: http://guides.grails.org/server-sent-events/guide/index.html